# Cast form NSData to unrelated type Data always Fails -- Swift 3 NSData to Data conversion error.

Tags: swift, nsdata

I have been trying to figure this out for a couple days with no success. 
This question has been asked before but the answers must be out of date as I can find no working solution. The error Xcode is giving me is strange too.

I have saved data in Core Data which saves it as NSData. I am retrieving that data and attempting to convert it to 'Data' for the ultimate purpose of creating a UIImage(data: THEData).

```
   let imageData = item?.image as! Data
       let newImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
```

'item' is my Core Data entity that holds the NSData type attribute of 'image'. (I have 'Allows External Storage' which from what I read allows Core Data to store large data files externally)

the first line

```
let imageData = item?.image as! Data
```

gives me an error: "Cast from NSData? to unrelated type Data always fails.

while the second line

```
let newImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
```

gives an error of: Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected argument type 'Data'

I am not sure what is going on here, as I can't even make sense of these errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: did you try with **let imageData = item?.image as! NSData**

Comment: Have you tried unwrapping without force unwrapping? And printing the type of object/NSData that your imageData is coming back as when you retrieve it?

Comment: var imageData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: item?.image)

Comment: `if let data = item?.image as? Data { let image = UIImage(data: data) }`

Comment: Have you declared your own `Data` type? (which will shadow `Foundation`'s `Data`)

Comment: @nazmul-hasan Thank you, I tried your suggestions and the JSONSerialization gave me an error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write'"

Comment: @kayla-galway Thank you. I have tried that and the type that is returned is Optional NSData

Comment: @eo-dabus Thank you. I tried your suggestion and got similar errors to my original post.

Comment: @hamish Thank you. I have not done that. Is that something that is needed to be done?

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. I have decided to just move on and not attempt to store image data in core data. I will store it separately like most people.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when converting my project from Swift 2 to Swift 3.1. I solved it by creating a completely new project in Xcode 8.3 and copying the necessary parts of the old code into it. The Data Core model must be created only in Xcode 8.3. 
It works for me.